# Makefile:I changed the directory of objs ,but all the files are compiled everytime

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I want to save all the generated .o files under the folder $(BUILD_DIR).

Although I did not edit any flies, all the src files will be recompiled.

Thanks to @JohnBollinger 's suggestion. I created a new project to test the problem.

My test project directory tree:

```
/test
   /app
      main.c
      Makefile
   /build_dir
      Makefile
   /bin
   Makefile
```

This is my top Makefile

```
TOPDIR := $(PWD)
CROSS_COMPILE :=


AS      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)as
LD      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
CC      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CPP     = $(CC) -E
AR      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ar
NM      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)nm
STRIP       = $(CROSS_COMPILE)strip
OBJCOPY     = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy
OBJDUMP     = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump

MARCH :=x86

SZ = $(CROSS_COMPILE)size

OPT = -O0
CFLAGS+= $(C_INCLUDES)
CFLAGS+= -g -gdwarf-2
CFLAGS+= $(OPT)

TARGET = test-$(MARCH)
BUILD_DIR = $(TOPDIR)/build_dir
BIN_DIR = $(TOPDIR)/bin


SUBDIRS = $(TOPDIR)/app \

export  CC CPP LD MARCH CFLAGS LDFLAGS TARGET CROSS_COMPILE
export BUILD_DIR BIN_DIR TOPDIR LINK_SCRIPT
export CPU ARCH MARCH BOARD

ALL:$(SUBDIRS)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -S $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin
    @echo  "\033[32mbuild success \033[0m"




$(SUBDIRS):ECHO
    @make clean
    @-mkdir -p bin
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
    echo -------------------compiling $$dir ------------------;\
    make -C $$dir || exit "$$?";\
    done
    @make -C $(BUILD_DIR)


ECHO:

.PHONY : clean ALL
clean:
    -rm $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o 
    -rm $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

here is my Makefile in app directory:

```c
objs += $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o

all:$(objs)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< -MD -MF $@.d

.PHONY: all
```

I tried `make -d`,and spotted:

```sh
 Considering target file '/home/alan/Desktop/test/build_dir/main.o'.
   File '/home/alan/Desktop/test/build_dir/main.o' does not exist.
   ...
   No need to remake target 'main.c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file '/home/alan/Desktop/test/build_dir/main.o'.
  Must remake target '/home/alan/Desktop/test/build_dir/main.o'.
```

Actually:

```sh
alan@alan-PC:~/Desktop/test/build_dir$ ls
main.o  main.o.d  Makefile
```

The main.o exist!

Why `make` think it doesn't exist?

Comment: "No need to remake target 'main.c'" means that file `main.c` itself will not be rebuilt.  This is the usual case for source files, and it does not imply that targets depending on `main.c` (such as an object file or a binary executable) will not be (re)built.

Comment: Files being rebuilt even though they are newer than their (supposed) prerequisites  is typically a symptom of `make` rules that do not actually build the targets they name. Sometimes such rules build different targets instead.  In this case, the offending rule is in some of the makefile code that you omitted, so we can't say much more about the problem as presented.  I suggest preparing and presenting a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand make problems, all that's required usually is to pay attention to the commands that make is running.  If they are not correct, then figure out why.

Your problem is right here:

```
$(SUBDIRS):ECHO
        @make clean
        ...
```

So the first thing you do for each subdirectory is run `make clean`.  That will of course delete all the object files:

```
clean:
        -rm $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o 
        -rm $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

So of course make will have to rebuild them.  If you examine the output that make prints, you'll see these commands that remove all object files, and you'll know why make is always rebuilding all the object files.

Also a note, you should *never* invoke a sub-make with the literal string `make`.  You should always use the variable `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}` if you prefer: same thing).

**Old Answer**

This:

```
SOURCES  =$(wildcard *.c) 
objs += $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/$(MARCH)-%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

Let's assume `BUILD_DIR` is set to `obj` and `MARCH` is set to `x86_64`.  Let's assume there is one file `foo.c`.  The we get this:

```
SOURCES = foo.c
objs = obj/x86_64-foo.o
```

Now you have defined this rule:

```
all: obj/x86_64-foo.o

obj/%.o:%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< -MD -MF $@.d
```

this can't work because the `%` in the target and prerequisite must be identical.  Here, the target's `%` matches `x86_64-foo` and so this rule will only match if the file `x86_64-foo.c` exists which, presumably, it doesn't.

I don't actually know how you get anything from this makefile except "don't know how to build target `obj/x86_64-foo.o`" so clearly there are things about this makefile you've omitted if it builds something for you.

If you write your rule like this instead:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(MARCH)-%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< -MD -MF $@.d
```

then it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer. I'm very sorry that I missed `$(MARCH)-` in the question. So, I edited my question with a simpler Makefile. The main.c will be compiled even I didn't edit it.

Comment: Thank you so much.I can't figure it out without you. I'm so careless